# Spring custom Authorization not working using @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

I am trying to implement custom `@PreAuthorize` method in my spring (3.2.2) mvc app. But whenever I click on the link which is supposed to take me to the controller method where the `@PreAuthorize` is implemented it gives me this error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:339)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:198)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    com.nav.qanda.admin.question.controller.AdminQuestionController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5bcda356_2.handleRequest(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

This is my app-servlet.xml

```
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
  </security:global-method-security>

  <bean id="expressionHandler" class="com.nav.panda.security.PandaMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

and these are the java files overriding

```
public class PandaMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler{
      @Override
      protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
              MethodInvocation invocation){
        PandaMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new PandaMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
        return root;
      }



public class PandaMethodSecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {


    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;


    public  boolean adminOnly() {
        System.out.println("Checking admin authority");
        return true;
//     return  this.hasAuthority("ADMIN");
    } ... other methods
```

And the controller looks like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createPandaPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      @PreAuthorize("adminOnly()")
      public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
           return new ModelAndView("admin/createPanda");
       }
```

web.xml :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

The login in my application will populate a User object (which has the users authority filled from a db read) from my application. How do I pass this User Object to check for authority ? And, what else would I need to do to get this working ?

Answer (score 3):

The request which leads to this method being called need to pass through the Spring Security filter chain, otherwise there will be no security context available when the permissions are checked.

Without seeing the rest of the stacktrace, I can't say 100%, but it looks like that's what's happening here, given the exception you are seeing (you should find similar issues if you search for the error message).

So you need to make sure all the requests you want secured are handled by the security filter chain, and also that your filter chain is properly configured (which it should be automatically if you're using the namespace).

Comment: I have updated the question with the complete stack trace. How do I ensure (other than the code posted) that the request is passing through the Spring Security filter ? And how do I tell Spring that my User object is the one that needs to be checked for user permissions.

Comment: I updated my web.xml with the spring security filter mappings (updated question) and now my app doesn't load at all

Comment: Is there an example around which shows how one could use custom Authorization annotations along with custom Authentication mechanism that will work with spring security ?